# How do I add the nodes' IDs and locations that are situated on a helix in space to a set in ADPL?

Tags: ansys, ansys-apdl

I have a beam structure in the form of a Helix. How do I add the nodes positioned on this helix using ANSYS APDL ?

I need to add the locations and IDs in separte sets.

Comment: What do you mean by "add the nodes"? Is it the node numbers? Also, do you intend to plot their locations?

Comment: Dear @Oska, I wrote : nodes' IDs. I need to use the ID and locations of each node in a next operation

Comment: Is there any need to plot them? If not, select your lines, then nodes attached, and the `*get` function will be your friend. You can update your answer with a small working example if you wish.